# PHP-GD: preserve half-transparent areas

Tags: php, transparency, php-gd

I'm in need of a generic image upload for a PHP site. Photos and Logos should be re-sized to a certain extend to make sure they're not too big and fit the design.

I'm trying it with this code:

```
function resize($width,$height) {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    if($this->image_type == PNG or $this->image_type == GIF) {
        imagealphablending($new_image, false);
        imagesavealpha($new_image,true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
    }

    imagecopyresized($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
    $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

However, when I upload an image that has areas with alpha-values between 0 and 255, they get replaced by a complete black, turning anti-aliased areas to a black border.

The full transparency works fine for PNG and GIF, merely the half-transparent areas are a problem.

I apologise if I'm not using the correct terms to explain my problem, maybe that's why I hardly found anything on it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443699/how-to-draw-semi-transparent-rectangle-in-php

Comment: cannot reproduce, problem is probably somewhere else, for example, if image is PNG, is `imagecreatefrompng` used? you can replace `imagefilledrectangle` with `imagefill`, and `imagecopyresized` to `imagecopyresampled`, also it's good if you add `imagealphablending($this->image, true);`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function resize($width,$height) {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    if($this->image_type == PNG or $this->image_type == GIF) {
        imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TRANSPARENT);
        imagesavealpha($new_image,true);
        imagealphablending($new_image, true);
    }

    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
    $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Disk.php#L181) (which I know it works).